# GNU Make does not execute recipe line

Tags: foreach, makefile

Given the following part of a Makefile:

```
$(call pkg-source,$(1)):
$(call unpack,$(call tarball,$(1)))
$(foreach pch, $(sort $(wildcard src/$(notdir $(ver_$(1))).patch*)), patch -d $(1)* -p1 < $(pch))
$(foreach var, $(shell find $(1)* -type f -iname abc.xyz), cp my_abc.xyz $(var))
touch $$@
noopstop
```

The noopstop is there to force make to terminate with "command not found".

First run after `make clean`, external source is unpacked, then (the first `foreach`) patched (if patches are present).

Then (the second `foreach`) a file of a known name that came with the source has to be overwritten by my own version. This always fails on the first run, yet the file is there.

Removing the file created by `touch $$@`, and running `make` again, the file is now replaced.

Starting `make` with the `-j1` option does not make a difference; the `-d` option does not help to find the problem either.

The GNU Make pages state: "Normally, make will execute only one recipe at a time, waiting for it to finish before executing the next." So after the first `foreach` (for patching), why doesn't the second see the file?

This is on Fedora_35, x86_64, GNU make 4.3

Thanks, Mat

Comment: How do you know that it fails? On which step does it fail? Can you give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Beta,I am sorry for not providing a complete example, I thought I had a simple misunderstanding of how make works.

I can detect that the file replacement did not work because the file is still the original date and size, not the size and date from when the copy did go well.
To me, it still looks that the foreach does not pick up changes in directory contents made during recipe execution.
I will try to make a full example, but it's a complicated Makefile.

Comment: I tried to make a simple makefile to demonstrate the problem, but each time I have one the problem also disappears. I have given up on this approach, because elsewhere in the makefile I found another method to do what I wanted, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to understand your example because you haven't provided it in the context of an actual rule.  But I'll assume that the entirety of the content you provide above is in some `define` variable that you are using with `call`.  But, the details of how this is used are *critical* and you don't provide them.

The problem is that you're doing all this work with make variables and functions, not shell commands.  The way make works is that all lines of the entire recipe are expanded first (so all make variables and functions are expanded), and only after that is complete will make invoke a shell with each line of the recipe one at a time.

A good rule of thumb is that if you ever find yourself running the make `shell` function in a recipe, you're probably doing something wrong.  A recipe is already run in a shell, so there's little to gain except confusion by using make's `shell` function.

In addition, your operations will not work correctly if they ever find more than one file.

For example:

```
$(foreach pch, $(sort $(wildcard src/$(notdir $(ver_$(1))).patch*)), patch -d $(1)* -p1 < $(pch))
```

Suppose the `wildcard` here expands to two files, `src/xyz.patch-01` and `src/xyz.patch-02`.  Now the result of expanding this will be something like:

```
patch -d foo* -p1 < src/xyz.patch-01 patch -d foo* -p1 < src/xyz.patch-02
```

which is clearly wrong.  If you want to have a make `foreach` loop expand to multiple shell commands, you have to remember to add a semicolon or `&&` to separate the commands:

```
$(foreach pch, ..., patch -d $(1)* -p1 < $(pch) &&) true
```

You'll have the same problem with the other command, except you don't want to do this with a make `foreach` and `shell` anyway as I discussed above.  You should be using shell constructs here, not make constructs:

```
for pch in $$(ls -1 src/$(notdir $(ver_$(1))).patch*); do \
    patch -d $(1)* -p1 < $$pch; \
done
for var in $$(find $(1)* -type f -iname abc.xyz); do \
    cp my_abc.xyz $$var; \
done
```

Comment: The patching DOES work, has been doing so for years.
For instance, if $(1) is "libaom", and the src directory contains
`libaom-v3.2.0.patch0`
`libaom-v3.2.0.patch1`
`libaom-v3.2.0.tar.xz`  

then the source is unpacked into directory libaom-v3.2.0 and the make log shows  

`tar -xJf src/libaom-v3.2.0.tar.xz`
`patch -d libaom* -p1 < src/libaom-v3.2.0.patch0`
`patching file CMakeLists.txt`
`patch -d libaom* -p1 < src/libaom-v3.2.0.patch1`
`patching file aom_ports/arm_cpudetect.c`

Sorry about the formatting, I am still learning

Comment: It won't work: if it works for you then there must be something materially different about your environment than what you've shown us here.  A foreach loop in make is a simple text substitution.  It doesn't know anything about running commands, or even what a command IS.  If you have `$(foreach A, 1 2 3, echo $A)` the result will be the TEXT `echo 1 echo 2 echo 3`.  There are no newlines or command separators here so when this text is sent to the shell it will see a single `echo` command with arguments `1 echo 2 echo 3`, NOT three different echo commands.

Comment: Ah, I start to understand. I miscopied the `foreach line`, in reality it is`'$(foreach pch,$(sort $(wildcard src/$(notdir $(ver_$(1))).patch*)), 
    patch -d $(1)* -p1 < $(pch))`  
so there is a newline in there, I did not know it mattered.
(Can´t get the newline before the patch statement, it is indented by two tabs).

Comment: It starts to work, I kept the 'foreach' for now, the sort is critical as patches must be applied in a specific order determined by the last part of the patch file name.
The `for var ...`  loops almost work, except that the file is copied to (literally) `ar` , so the two dollar signs plus the first character of `var` are eaten. What am I missing still?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your situation; it's not possible to see how things are set up using comments where you can't get correct formatting.  Please edit your question and add more context: exactly what is that code you quote doing?  I guess it's in a `define`/`endef`?  Please show that.  Then please show an actual rule where that `define` is used so we can see how it's used.  There's absolutely no way to solve variable expansion issues without knowing the complete environment.

Comment: Also, I really advise against relying on newlines embedded in make functions... I'm actually surprised it works at all.  You should be using shell constructs, such as I suggested above with `&&` instead: that's much safer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was unable to work on it for two days, I appreciate your patience. 1) It is possible that make's `foreach` is used instead of the shell's `for` to make it independent of the shell used. 2) There are indeed a number of functions and variables defined, I am making a Makefile without such things, that should clear any confusion. 3) I think this construct with a new line results in as many patch lines created by `foreach` as there are patch files found. 4) The only problem I have left is that in the `var for ...` loop the `$$var` is replaced by `ar` instead of `$var` . Ideas?

Comment: It means a variable that you want to be escaped from expansion by make, is not being escaped so make expands the `$v` to empty (because it's not set).  There's no way to guess why that is without seeing exactly what the definition is, and also how it's being used in the makefile.

Comment: Thank you for your support, but I could not get the variable expansion to work in this makefile. I found another method in the same makefile that achieves what I wanted, so I have given up on the "copy file" method. I have learned a lot about GNU make though, thank you for your patience.